# Is it possible to use a perforce workspace on unix and windows machine both?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I want to create  a perforce workspace on a unix machine and edit files in the workspace on the same machine. Then use the p4v client on a windows machine to access the unix workspace, manage changelist for the files changed on unix and submit them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using a network mounting approach, such as Samba, to access the Unix files from your Windows PC?

Generally speaking, it is possible to do what you want.

Two specific challenges you'll face:

1. Your workspace has to avoid being "host-locked", so make sure that you do **not** specify a hostname in your workspace definition. If you specify a hostname, the server will only allow you to use that workspace from that host.
2. You'll have to struggle with line ending conventions, because Windows uses one set of line ending conventions and Unix uses a different set of conventions. Read closely about the 'share' setting for line end conventions in the workspace specification: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html#Processi

Comment: An alternate solution to the "host lock" problem is to set P4HOST on one or both machines.  E.g. if your machines are `ps-unix` and `ps-win`, you can set your client Host to `ps-win` and then do `p4 set P4HOST=ps-win` on your `ps-unix` machine to tell Perforce that you want to treat it as the same client host.